# Add events to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to add some simple actions that should be done automatically each time I execute the cell or save the notebook. Let's imagine I want to make a log of some of my activities in notebook (`ipynb`, the json) metadata.

For example, let's image I want to do following:

- each time I run cell I want to store such information in metadata so I will know exactly when and which cell I executed,
- after each notebook save (`Ctrl+S`) I want to perform some postprocessing and generate some report,
- after each copy/paste (`Ctrl+C`/`Ctrl+V`) I want to check the clipboard and process it.

Is it possible to somehow implement it in Jupyter Notebook? I need it to be embedded to notebook file (not as external extension that user need to install and turn on).